# Java Positive flow and negative flow exception handling

Tags: java, exception, stoppropagation

I am writing a Java code to fetch the object information by passing the object id. My case will be like this: 
1. Its not necessary that all Object ID's have information which means returns null.
2. But  If the ID has a information, then I will return the object. So I am doing null check here.

If I write a else condition which throws the KalturaApiException, then its throwing the exception saying EntryId not found and stopping the execution there. My problem is it should continue with the positive flow and should log all the ids with no information. How to handle this scenario and how to catch this exception. Please help me resolving this. Thanks in advance.

```
try {
entryInfo = getMedia(entry);
                            if (entryInfo != null) {
//Here I am retrieving all the information from the object and setting to one more object.
}
}catch(KalturaApiException e){
 e.getMessage();
}
```

Inside getMedia method:

```
try {
        entryInfo = mediaService.get(entryId);
        if (entryInfo != null) {
            return entryInfo;
        }
    } catch (KalturaApiException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return entryInfo;
```

Comment: if you are prepared to handle a null result from getMedia, why do you throw an exception in getMedia? If non-existent media is sometimes error and sometimes not, have 2 calls: one that returns null, such as getMedia, and one that throws, such as getExistingMedia().

Comment: Exactly, this'd actually throw an error about exception being never thrown in body of `try` block in first piece of code

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Arkadiy  - So You mean to say I can have two calls one which gets all the id's with Information and the other which gets all the id's with no information which inturn can go to logs. There is no need to handle exception here. Please correct me if anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, mediaService.get also throw KalturaApiException.
I think you don't need to worry about it. So inside getMedia you can just

```
return mediaService.get(entryId);
```

null also an object and you do null check in the other method. Exception also will be catched in your first method. (don't forget sign `getMedia(long id) throw KalturaApiException {...}`)

```
try {
entryInfo = getMedia(entry);
if (entryInfo != null) {
// do something
}
}catch(KalturaApiException e){
 e.getMessage(); //log information, it's better to use logger (log4j for example)
}
```

Comment: Now I am not handling the exception in getMedia method. getMedia(String entryId)
   throws KalturaApiException {
  KalturaMediaService mediaService = client.getMediaService();
  return mediaService.get(entryId); In the first method, I am doing null check, so when its null  its going to catch and giving the message.But its not proceeding with the next execution with positive scenario for all the remaining id's which have information.I have this code inside for loop. for (String entry : mediaList) {
       if (entry != null) {
        entryInfo = getMedia(entry);
        if (entryInfo != null) {

Comment: Now I am not handling the exception in getMedia method. getMedia(String entryId) throws KalturaApiException { KalturaMediaService mediaService = client.getMediaService(); return mediaService.get(entryId); In the first method, I am doing null check, so when its null its going to catch and giving the message.But its not proceeding with the next execution with positive scenario for all the remaining id's which have information.I have this code inside for loop. for (String entry : mediaList) { if (entry != null) { entryInfo = getMedia(entry); if (entryInfo != null) { –